# If a, b are real numbers such that $x^3-ax^2 + bx – 6 = 0$ has its roots real and positive, then minimum value of b is

Tags: derivatives

The options given are:

(A) $1$

(B) $2$

(C) $\sqrt[3]36$

(D) None of these

Using the basic definition of product of roots and such, I can infer that $b>0$. But I can't move ahead from that.

**Update**:
Apart from the AM-GM method as suggested by an answer below, how can this question be solved using Calculus?
(As this question was given to me as part of the 'Application of Derivatives' topic).

Comment: People on these boards don't just give away answers, with a question like this you'll be lucky if you get a hint, without showing any effort of yourself. How did you infer that b has to be larger than zero?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. It cannot avoid having a positive root regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$. So does the statement mean that it has **only** positive roots? Or does **roots** (plural) means that it has at least two distinct positive roots? It seems to be a poorly worded problem, which, unfortunately, is not uncommon.

Comment: Also, there is no point in putting a negative sign in front of the coefficient $\mathbf{a}$ since we are told only that $\mathbf{a}$ is a real number. Presumably, one is supposed to use Descartes' Rule of Signs. Perhaps they intended to indicate that the coefficient of $x^2$ should be negative? Who can tell?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales The question is from a competitive examination, so maybe that negative sign on $a$ was only to throw some students off.

Comment: @HarshaG. Good point. And it is possible to have all roots positive for certain positive values of  $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I edited the question now. Is it less ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, that makes it clear that **all** its roots must be real and positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: use that $$x^3-x^2(x_1+x_2+x_3)+x(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)-x_1x_2x_3=
x^3-ax^2+bx-6$$ and AM-GM
$$\frac{x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{x_1^2x_2^2x_3^2}=\sqrt[3]{36}$$
therefore?

Comment: You made a typo, you meant  $= x^3 - ax^2 + bx - 6$

Comment: How do apply AM-GM here? I did use $(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4)$ = $b/a$, and from that I was only able to figure that $b>0$ because the product and addition of all the positive roots has to be positive.

Comment: typo is corrected

Comment: thanks for the help @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: you are welcome and think of $AM-GM$

Comment: It still says $x^2$ where it should be $x^3$ tho. Maybe just trying to be a bit annoying since you just give him the answer :P

Comment: thank you typo is corrected

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Is there any possibility to use graph or any other method to solve this? I mean this question was given to me under the "Applications of Derivatives" module, so how can I approach it with that?

Comment: at the time i don't know the answer